# Delete only specific item from localstorage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to **store** **Storageselectedclient** even after client **logout** from my website so that when we logins again the last selected clients will shown up but it's not working also my whole project is in **Angular 7**.

[image]

Here is my working code which has also **Idle logout** feature in it

```
  var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
      var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

      document.onclick = function () {
          _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
      };

      document.onmousemove = function () {
          _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
      };

      document.onkeypress = function () {
          _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
      };
      $(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
       });
       window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);


      function CheckIdleTime() {
          _idleSecondsCounter++;
          var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
          if (oPanel)
              oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
          if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
              localStorage.clear();
              window.location.replace(location.origin);

          }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please share the structure of the data you store in localStorage?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz It's shown in the image

Comment: Sorry but imgur.com is banned in my country :D

Comment: You can use `localStorage.removeItem('item-key')`, for more info => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the data with **removeItem()**

```
localStorage.removeItem('key')
```

Using **clear()** will clear all local storage.

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: I need to store some object not want to clear whole local storage @HirenMakwana

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay You can use localStorage.setItem("keyName", {}) to store object and localStorage.getItem("keyName") to get object.

Comment: apologies but this solution isn't works excatly as i need to store client id so that if someone is autologout after idle time if he logins again last client id is selected

Comment: If you have any solution that will be much appreciated and any suggestion although i am going to accept it no issues brother.